# How to detect whether the focused window is an Edit 'type' control?

Tags: c++, winapi

How can I detect whether the focused window is an Edit 'type' control? One method I am aware of is using [Microsoft Active Accessibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is looking like it will involve alot of effort using this method.

Is there another method I could use that is simpler?

My use-case is: when an edit control has the focus, store that `hwnd`.

```
// Callback set by SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, NULL, (WINEVENTPROC)&winEventProc, 0, 0, WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);
void CALLBACK KeyboardComponent::winEventProc(HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook, DWORD  event, HWND hwnd, LONG idObject,
    LONG idChild, DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
    // if hwnd == "Edit Control" store hwnd to send key input events

    // One technique but not comprehensive
    TCHAR wndClassName[255];
    GetClassName(hwnd, wndClassName, 255);

    if (_tcsicmp(wndClassName, _T("edit")) == 0)
        targetEdit = hwnd;

    // Class names I am receiving are subclassed or new window classes that look and operate like Edit controls.
    // Ie when clicking the Firefox address bar I get: MozillaWindowClass
    // Ie when clicking the Chrome address bar I get:  Chrome_WidgetWin_1
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code? Using the Windows API one would look at the window class name, which is exactly what you are doing.

Comment: I must down vote this question, because, If I want EDIT class and get EDIT class, is this what I want. OP has problem understanding that not all controls that looks are edit control are 'edit' class.

Comment: I don't think you really understand what you are doing here. Who says that the control is even windowed. You've already found the right solution, UI Automation. Stop running from it.

Comment: What do you plan on doing with that `hwnd` you wish to store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active Accessibility is the correct solution.  You can use [`AccessibleObjectFromEvent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317976.aspx) to get an [`IAccessible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318466.aspx) interface for the `HWND` that is triggering your `winEventProc` hook, and then check the [`IAccessible::AccRole`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318485.aspx) property for `ROLE_SYSTEM_TEXT`:

> ROLE_SYSTEM_TEXT
>   The object represents selectable text that allows edits or is designated as read-only.

For example:

```
// Callback set by SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, NULL, (WINEVENTPROC)&winEventProc, 0, 0, WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);
void CALLBACK KeyboardComponent::winEventProc(HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook, DWORD  event, HWND hwnd, LONG idObject,
    LONG idChild, DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
    IAccessible* pAcc = NULL;
    VARIANT varChild;
    HRESULT hr = AccessibleObjectFromEvent(hwnd, idObject, idChild, &pAcc, &varChild);  
    if ((hr == S_OK) && (pAcc != NULL))
    {
        VARIANT varRole;
        hr = pAcc->get_accRole(varChild, &varRole);
        if ((hr == S_OK) && (varRole.vt == VT_I4) && (varRole.lVal == ROLE_SYSTEM_TEXT))
        {
            // ... 
        }
        pAcc->Release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For reliable result try using `RealGetWindowClass`, it should deal with a case when window was subclassed. If you don't care about that use regular `GetClassName`.

In case you want to handle controls that are not derived from standard Edit class, none of that will work of course.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this code to know if focused window is Edit control

```
CWnd* pControl; 
pControl = this->GetFocus();

if(pControl->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CEdit))){
      //----
       -----
       ----//
}
```

Get more details [Here](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?401032-GetFocus-How-do-you-determine-the-Control-type-that-has-focus)

Convert `Cwnd` to `HWND`

```
pControl->GetSafeHwnd();
```

Comment: This only works if you are using MFC and if the Edit in question was subclassed

Comment: ...and for a control in your own program. Given that this person is writing an accessibility client, none of the three things are the case.